# JavaScript - Search for element in array that includes SOME of text

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find in an array includes SOME of the text in an element. Here is what I have:

```
['red', 'green', 'blue'].some(e => e.includes('red:square')) // false
```

Which returns `false`. But I would like it to return `true` because obviously `red` is inside one of the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 console.log(['red', 'green', 'blue'].some(e => ['red','square'].includes(e))) //positive test case 


 console.log(['red', 'green', 'blue'].some(e => ['white','square'].includes(e))) //negative test case
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Alternation ( | )** and **[Search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)** function

```js
console.log(['red', 'green', 'blue'].some(e => e.search(/red|square/)))
```